# Error in table: all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r

I am trying to use naiveBayes to fit and classify a data with binary (location=3 or not) outcome and assess its performance on test data by resampling.

I got an error code:
Error in table(train$prog, trainPred) :
all arguments must have the same length

Here is my reproducible code:

```
wifiDat <- read.table("wifi_localization.txt",sep="\t")
colnames(wifiDat) 
dim(wifiDat)
summary(wifiDat)
head(wifiDat)
colnames(wifiDat) <- c("WF1", "WF2", "WF3", "WF4", "WF5", "WF6",  "WF7", "RM")
wifiDat$RM <- factor(wifiDat$RM)
library(e1071)
wifiDat$RM <- factor(wifiDat$RM)
set.seed(1)
row.number = sample(1:nrow(wifiDat), 0.25*nrow(wifiDat))
train = wifiDat[row.number,]
test = wifiDat[-row.number,]
NBclassfier=naiveBayes(RM~WF1+WF2+WF3+WF4+WF5+WF6+WF7, data=train)
print(NBclassfier)
printALL=function(model){
trainPred=predict(model, newdata = train, type = "class")
trainTable=table(train$prog, trainPred)
testPred=predict(NBclassfier, newdata=test, type="class")
testTable=table(test$prog, testPred)
trainAcc=(trainTable[1,1]+trainTable[2,2]+trainTable[3,3])/sum(trainTable)
testAcc=(testTable[1,1]+testTable[2,2]+testTable[3,3])/sum(testTable)
message("Contingency Table for Training Data")
print(trainTable)
message("Contingency Table for Test Data")
print(testTable)
message("Accuracy")
print(round(cbind(trainAccuracy=trainAcc, testAccuracy=testAcc),3))
}
printALL(NBclassfier)
```

Here is my sample data

```
V1. V2. V3. V4. V5. V6. V7. V8
-64 -56 -61 -66 -71 -82 -81 1
-68 -57 -61 -65 -71 -85 -85 2
-63 -60 -60 -67 -76 -85 -84 3
-61 -60 -68 -62 -77 -90 -80 4
-63 -65 -60 -63 -77 -81 -87 1
-64 -55 -63 -66 -76 -88 -83 1
-65 -61 -65 -67 -69 -87 -84 2
-61 -63 -58 -66 -74 -87 -82 3
-65 -60 -59 -63 -76 -86 -82 4
-62 -60 -66 -68 -80 -86 -91 1
-67 -61 -62 -67 -77 -83 -91 1
-65 -59 -61 -67 -72 -86 -81 1
-63 -57 -61 -65 -73 -84 -84 1
```

Please how can I fix the error?

Comment: Hi Jimmy! Can you please update your code to include a command that creates your object `wifiDat`? That would make it a lot easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the traceback of your error, you should see that the issue lies in the `table(train$prog, trainPred)` part of your function. The `base::table()` function requires you to provide objects of the same length for the `...` argument, as

Stepping through your custom function, you'll see that the length of `trainPred` is 3, and `train$prog` doesn't exist (and all columns of `train` are of length 10 anyway). Hence the error.

Are you missing a step somewhere?